# Python ProcessPoolExecutor process inside gRPC server dies without throwing any errors

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures, grpc-python

I have a `gRPC` server which uses `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `max_workers=1` to run a script. [Here](https://www.paulsprogrammingnotes.com/2014/10/large-dictionaries-not-released-from.html) is why i had to use a ProcessPoolExecutor inside `run_brain_application` with `max_workers=1`. Below is the simplified version of the server script.

I've put two print statements to print the begining and ending of the `process`.

The issue is that sometimes, for some requests, the process starts but never finishes. I mean it prints `START`, but I never see the `STOP`. The same request works the next time, hence the issue is not with the request. Also, if there is an exception inside the `run_application`, it's thrown without any issues.

I've checked all the related questions on Stackoverflow, but most of them ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303020/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-dying-silently), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122582/how-can-i-catch-when-a-thread-dies-in-threadpoolexecutor)) are about their processes not throwing exceptions, which is not my case.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
class BrainServer(brain_pb2_grpc.BrainServiceServicer):

    def run_brain_application(self, request, context):
            request_dict = MessageToDict(
                request, 
                preserving_proto_field_name=True,
                keep_null=True
            )

            print("START")
            with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
                result = executor.submit(run_application, request_dict).result()
            res = result.get('data')
            print("STOP")
            report = dict_to_protobuf(result_pb2.Result, {res_type: res}, strict=False)

            return report

        except Exception as e:
            _log_fatal(
                msg=str(e)
            )
            raise e


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16))
    brain_pb2_grpc.add_BrainServiceServicer_to_server(BrainServer(), server)

    server.add_insecure_port(f"[::]:{GRPC_PORT}")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

Comment: Regarding the reasoning, did you run into that issue yourself? It's been 7 years after all. You could also try using `joblib` instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor`. It's manual claims it is better at handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard one to pinpoint.

I would first recommend to add timeouts to your Executors.

Also I would recommend to use only `ThreadPoolExecutor` and see if the issue is resolved. The python `logger` and maybe some other components are not behaving nicely when used in a multi process environment. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641488/5372462). My guess is that you are using python resources which are not supposed to be shared across processes, but they are (The `logger` is my immediate suspect)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a child process with `os.fork` when a parent process is multi-threaded is problematic.
The `multiprocesing` module which `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` uses internally gives more than one way to create a child process. These ways are called start methods and they're named as *fork*, *spawn* and *forkserver*.

The *forkserver* method is recommended for a multi-threaded parent to create children because in *forkserver* method a server is created which is single-threaded and the multi-threaded parent requests the server to create a child. Since the server is single-threaded `os.fork`ing is not problematic.

The `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` takes `mp_context` parameter which it uses to set the start method for the processes in the pool.
So you should pass `mp_context`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ctx = mp.get_context('forkserver')
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1, mp_context=ctx) as executor:
    result = executor.submit(run_application, request_dict).result()
res = result.get('data')
```

[Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)